# AWK epoch diff with current and previous line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file like this called `Sample`:-

```
206,,,206,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:00:05
206,,,206,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:00:21
205,,,205,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:00:23
205,,,205,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:00:29
207,,,207,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:00:34
205,,,205,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:00:40
204,,,204,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:00:46
202,,,202,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:00:52
201,,,201,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:01:00
202,,,202,14.9,0,2012/04/24 00:01:04
```

And the following AWK command:-

```
awk -F, '{ gsub("/"," ",$7); gsub(":"," ",$7); t+=(mktime($7)-mktime(p)); printf ("%s,%s,%s\n",mktime($7),mktime(p),t); p=$7 }' Sample
```

Giving the following output:-

```
1335222005,-1,1335222006
1335222021,1335222005,1335222022
1335222023,1335222021,1335222024
1335222029,1335222023,1335222030
1335222034,1335222029,1335222035
1335222040,1335222034,1335222041
1335222046,1335222040,1335222047
1335222052,1335222046,1335222053
1335222060,1335222052,1335222061
1335222064,1335222060,1335222065
```

for each line, the 7th column is converted to an epoch date and the difference between the epoch date on the previous line is calculated and added to `t`.

On the first line being processed, because `p` is currently not a date, mktime returns `-1` throwing out my figures.

What I want to do is, tell the AWK script, if line 1 is being processed then assume the difference is 6. At the moment it is subtracting -1 from 1335222005 resulting in 1335222006.

I want to say, start `t` at 6, then on the second line, work out the difference in epoch seconds to the previous line and increment `t` by that amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do something special for line 1.

```
awk -F, '
    {gsub(/[\/:]/," ",$7); this_time = mktime($7)}
    NR != 1 {t += this_time - prev_time; print this_time, prev_time, t}
    {prev_time = this_time}
' << END
```

Given your input data, this prints

```
1335240021 1335240005 16
1335240023 1335240021 18
1335240029 1335240023 24
1335240034 1335240029 29
1335240040 1335240034 35
1335240046 1335240040 41
1335240052 1335240046 47
1335240060 1335240052 55
1335240064 1335240060 59
```

Alternately, a convenient way to initialize a variable is with awk'f `-v` option

```
awk -v t=6 '... same as before ...'
```

Comment: Have managed to do what I wanted to do using a variation of this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In `awk` you can initialize a variable in a `BEGIN` block, and exist two variables to get line number, both are useful for your case, `FNR` and `NR`:

```
BEGIN { t = 6 }
```

or

```
FNR == 1 { t = 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Would using `BEGIN` ([see here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html)) help?
That will allow initialization of t variable to whatever you want. Something like

```
  awk -F, 'BEGIN {t=6} { gsub("/"," ",$7); gsub(":"," ",$7); t+=(mktime($7)-mktime(p)); printf ("%s,%s,%s\n",mktime($7),mktime(p),t); p=$7 }' Sample
```